# Change X-axis Labels in cplot

Tags: r, plot

I have a logistic regression model and I want to plot the average marginal effects of each variable using the `cplot` function. But I have a categorical variable where the labels have long names, which causes the `cplot` to produce overlapping x-axis labels:

```
cplot(model,"Region", xlab = "Dwelling's Region")
```

[image: AME]

As you can see, because the names are long, it displays only half of them. How can I create a plot without x-labels, but only numbers, from 1 to 12. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
cplot(model,"Region", xlab = "Dwelling's Region")
axis(1, at = 1:12, labels = 1:12)
```

[image: img]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `cplot()` passes additional arguments to default graphics methods. The standard way to turn-off the drawing of x-axis is by setting `xaxt='n'`. Search for `xaxt` in `help(par)`.

In your case this should work:

```
cplot(model,"Region", xlab = "Dwelling's Region", xaxt='n')
axis(1, at = 1:12, labels = 1:12)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives the same result as my second plot above.

Comment: Please share more details, so I can get the same plot you show in your example and check myself. A bit hard to guess now what might be going wrong when I cannot get the same result as you.